# How to get two DIVs with widths that add to 100% next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I have two DIVs (Nav and Main). When their widths add to 100%, the second always floats underneath the first. If I change the first DIV's width to 19% and the second to 79%, they float side by side but with a 2% strip of white space to the right.

How can I get the 2 DIVs to sit side by side (even after resizing the window) so they combine to fill 100% of the page width?

Here is the code and it is being tested in Chrome:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Space</title>
  <style>
    #header h1 {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 40pt;
      font-family: Century Gothic;
    }
    #header {
      background: aqua;
    }
    #nav {
      height: 100%;
      width: 19%;
      float: left;
      background: lightblue;
    }
    #nav p {
      font-size: 20pt;
      font-family: Century Gothic;
      color: yellow;
    }
    #main {
      float: left;
      padding-left: 20px;
      background: linear-gradient(white, blue);
      width: 79%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">
    <br>
    <h1>All About Space</h1>
    <br>
  </div>



  <div id="nav">
    <p>Mercury</p>
    <p>Venus</p>
    <p>Earth</p>
    <p>Mars</p>
    <p>Saturn</p>
    <p>Jupiter</p>
    <p>Uranus</p>
    <p>Neptune</p>
  </div>



  <div id="main">
    <h3>This website is all about space</h3>
    <img src="http://marshall.org/wp-content/themes/marshall/img/featured-space-policy.jpg" alt="" height="200px" width="400px">
    <p>Clicking on the links to the right and you will learn all about the planets of the solar system</p>
    <p>Maybe one day we will all be able to visit some of them!</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add a wrapper div as a container for those 2 div and have display:flex in the wrapper style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem here you are using box-sizing: content-box (default value) so you need careful about padding, margin calculation if px used at some point different browser size will break the layout. we have to you use proper percentage value for all layout property like padding, margin, border etc.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background: lightblue;
}

#main {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(white, blue);
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you. Could you explain why the original code would not work and what the additional box-sizing code does? Thanks

Comment: @sw123456 How about a quick google search on `box-sizing`. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: @sw123456 The quick answer will be: because `box-sizing: border-box` set the width to include the padding as well as the content, while `box-sizing: content-box` set the width as the content only. If you set `width: 80%; padding-left: 20px`, that makes the element's border size to be 80% + 20px, which will result in more than 100% and the two DIVs will break the line. Read more about `box-sizing`: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the expected result

```
#nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 19%;
  float: left;
  background: lightblue;
}
#nav p {
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  color: yellow;
}
#main {
  float: left;

  background: linear-gradient(white, blue);
  width: 81%;
  height: 100%;
}
img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

remove `padding-left`of the main div, and make IMG's `max-width:100%`